# How to clear all cache and local data upon logout in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am going to clear all cache and local data upon logout in the Kotlin application.
I used cacheDir.deleteRecursively() when clicking the logout button in the logoutragment.

```
context!!.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
```

But it is not working.
How can you help me?

Comment: What are you using to cache your local data?

Comment: I am using room

Comment: if you wan to database data, you should create method to delete the table completely

Answer (score -1):

You need to create Dao, in your Dao make something like this:

```
@Dao 
interface MyDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM table_name")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Furthermore, if you are using MVVM architecture, you need to create Repository and ViewModel. After that observe ViewModel in your Activity/Fragment. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0) codelab and [this](https://medium.com/@ruwan.se.uok/android-apps-using-mvvm-with-clean-archite) for more info about MVVM.